# Where to start with optimizing/adding indexes to speed up query?

Tags: mysql, search, optimization, indexing

I'm not really sure where to start with cutting down this query in the search section of my site so that it doesn't take so long.  You run a search on a variety of tables, and get filtered results back mainly from the "Items" table, and currently it (and searched like it) take sometimes over 10 seconds.  Part of the problem is that the php code that composes the sql is dirty as hell, of course, and I'm not used to having huge queries that I need to optimize in general, but what techniques can I use to determine where to add indexes in a query like this?

### The query

```
SELECT
    items.ItemId,
    items.Name,
    items.BrandCode,
    items.BrandCategoryId,
    items.CatalogPage,
    items.PriceRetail,
    items.PriceSell,
    items.PriceHold,
    items.Descr,
    items.GenderId,
    products.ImagetnURL,
    products.FlagDefault,
    products.ProductId,
    products.Code AS ProductCode,
    products.Name AS ProductName,
    brands.Name AS BrandName,
    items.FlagStatus AS ItemFlagStatus
FROM
    items,
    products,
    brands,
    productsizes,
    searchsizechartsizes,
    sizechartsizes
WHERE
    items.ItemId = products.ItemId AND
    items.BrandCode = brands.Code AND
    items.FlagStatus != 'U' AND
    products.FlagStatus != 'U' AND
    items.TypeId = '10' AND
    searchsizechartsizes.SearchSizeChartId = '11' AND
    searchsizechartsizes.Size = sizechartsizes.Size AND
    sizechartsizes.SizeChartId = productsizes.SizeChartId AND
    productsizes.ProductId = products.ProductId
GROUP BY
    items.ItemId
ORDER BY
    items.Name
LIMIT
    0, 15;
```

### Logs show 14 second execution time, and 3 million rows examined

```
# Query_time: 14  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 15  Rows_examined: 2901565
```

### Summary of query results

```
+--------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| ItemId | Name                 | BrandCode | BrandCategoryId | CatalogPage | PriceRetail | PriceSell | PriceHold | Descr | GenderId | ImagetnURL  | FlagDefault | ProductId | ProductCode | ProductName | BrandName         | ItemFlagStatus |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-
|   3376 | 10-inch Pull On Boot | RW        |            2801 |          24 |      189.99 |    189.99 |    189.99 | Full grain brown leather - blah blah blah |        1 | images/rw/rw-2249tn.jpg    | Y           |      4345 | 2249        | Brown Full Grain Turbo Vegas Leather                    | Red Wing Work     | A              | 
|   9340 | 11                   | RR        |            NULL |           1 |      300.00 |    300.00 |    300.00 | The Engineer 11" boot from Red Wing Shoes�  blah blah blah... |        1 | images/rr/rr-2990tn.jpg    | Y           |     16749 | 2990        | Black Harness Calfskin                                  | Red Wing Heritage | A              
~~~~~~ other results here redacted for space reasons ~~~~~~
15 rows in set (13.33 sec)
```

### Explain of the query

```
mysql> explain SELECT items.ItemId, items.Name, items.BrandCode, items.BrandCategoryId, items.CatalogPage, items.PriceRetail, items.PriceSell, items.PriceHold, items.Descr, items.GenderId, products.ImagetnURL, products.FlagDefault,  products.ProductId, products.Code as ProductCode, products.Name as ProductName, brands.Name as BrandName, items.FlagStatus as ItemFlagStatus  FROM items, products, brands, productsizes, searchsizechartsizes, sizechartsizes  WHERE items.ItemId = products.ItemId AND items.BrandCode = brands.Code AND items.FlagStatus != 'U' AND products.FlagStatus != 'U' AND items.TypeId = '10' AND (searchsizechartsizes.SearchSizeChartId = '11' AND searchsizechartsizes.Size = sizechartsizes.Size AND sizechartsizes.SizeChartId = productsizes.SizeChartId AND productsizes.ProductId = products.ProductId)   group by items.ItemId  ORDER BY items.Name LIMIT 0, 15;
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys                                  | key         | key_len | ref                                    | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | searchsizechartsizes | ref    | PRIMARY,Size                                   | PRIMARY     | 4       | const                                  |    2 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | brands               | ALL    | NULL                                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                   |   40 |                                 | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sizechartsizes       | ref    | Size,SizeChartId                               | Size        | 33      | shermanbros.searchsizechartsizes.Size  |  217 | Using where                     | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | productsizes         | ref    | ProductId,SizeChartId                          | SizeChartId | 5       | shermanbros.sizechartsizes.SizeChartId |   17 | Using where                     | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products             | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FlagStatus,flagstatusanddefault,ItemId | PRIMARY     | 4       | shermanbros.productsizes.ProductId     |    1 | Using where                     | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items                | eq_ref | PRIMARY,BrandCode,TypeId,FlagStatus,ItemsIndex | PRIMARY     | 4       | shermanbros.products.ItemId            |    1 | Using where                     | 
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

### Structure of the items table

```
mysql> show create table items;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| items | CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `ItemId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Code` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `BrandCode` char(2) default NULL,
  `CatalogPage` int(3) default NULL,
  `BrandCategoryId` int(11) default NULL,
  `TypeId` int(11) default NULL,
  `StyleId` int(11) default NULL,
  `GenderId` int(11) default NULL,
  `PriceRetail` decimal(6,2) default NULL,
  `PriceSell` decimal(6,2) default NULL,
  `PriceHold` decimal(6,2) default NULL,
  `Cost` decimal(6,2) default NULL,
  `PriceNote` longtext,
  `FlagTaxable` char(1) default NULL,
  `FlagStatus` char(1) default NULL,
  `FlagFeatured` char(1) default NULL,
  `MaintFlagStatus` char(1) default NULL,
  `Descr` longtext,
  `DescrNote` longtext,
  `ImagetnURL` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ImagefsURL` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ImagelsURL` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `DateCreated` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `DateStatus` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `AdminNote` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ItemId`),
  KEY `BrandCode` (`BrandCode`),
  KEY `Name` (`Name`),
  KEY `TypeId` (`TypeId`),
  KEY `StyleId` (`StyleId`),
  KEY `GenderId` (`GenderId`),
  KEY `FlagStatus` (`FlagStatus`),
  KEY `ItemsIndex` (`TypeId`,`FlagStatus`,`ItemId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10216 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 | 
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Existing indexes on the items table

```
mysql> show indexes from items;
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| items |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | ItemId      | A         |        8678 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | BrandCode  |            1 | BrandCode   | A         |          36 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | Name       |            1 | Name        | A         |        8678 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | TypeId     |            1 | TypeId      | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
|     items |          1 | StyleId    |            1 | StyleId     | A         |          41 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | GenderId   |            1 | GenderId    | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | FlagStatus |            1 | FlagStatus  | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | ItemsIndex |            1 | TypeId      | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | ItemsIndex |            2 | FlagStatus  | A         |          52 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| items |          1 | ItemsIndex |            3 | ItemId      | A         |        8678 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems to have an index on various columns already, but those indexes still leave it slow with regards to this search query. And one multi-index on typeid, flagstats, itemid that's there to optimize a seperate query.

And yeah, as you can see, the items table itself is a beast, which probably doesn't help.

Comment: First comment: The GROUP BY clause in the query makes no sense, you haven't used any aggregation functions. It should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your FROM and WHERE clauses:

```
FROM
    items,
    products,
    brands,
    productsizes,
    searchsizechartsizes,
    sizechartsizes
WHERE
    items.ItemId = products.ItemId AND
    items.BrandCode = brands.Code AND
    items.FlagStatus != 'U' AND
    products.FlagStatus != 'U' AND
    items.TypeId = '10' AND
    searchsizechartsizes.SearchSizeChartId = '11' AND
    searchsizechartsizes.Size = sizechartsizes.Size AND
    sizechartsizes.SizeChartId = productsizes.SizeChartId AND
    productsizes.ProductId = products.ProductId
```

you have put all of the join logic into the WHERE clause, which is unhelpful when reading the query. Using explicit join syntax instead, we can rewrite as the following:

```
FROM
    items
    JOIN products ON items.ItemId = products.ItemId
    JOIN brands ON items.BrandCode = brands.Code
    JOIN productsizes ON products.ProductId = productsizes.ProductId
    JOIN sizechartsizes ON sizechartsizes.SizeChartId = productsizes.SizeChartId
    JOIN searchsizechartsizes ON sizechartsizes.Size = searchsizechartsizes.Size
WHERE
    items.FlagStatus != 'U' AND
    items.TypeId = '10' AND
    products.FlagStatus != 'U' AND
    searchsizechartsizes.SearchSizeChartId = '11'
```

This makes it more clear what is going on.

It seems like you have a good candidate index for this query in ItemsIndex. (By the way - the index on TypeID alone is redundant and should be dropped, because TypeID is a left prefix of ItemsIndex.) Unfortunately MySQL's query optimiser seems to think it makes more sense to do the join back-to-front, starting with table searchsizechartsizes. I'm not sure why it would do this, but I notice that table brands apparently has no usable keys defined on it. It might be a good idea to look into this.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of this is the work of a previous developer.  I plan to rewrite the joins to be explicit when I can, they're a symptom of the way the sql is concatenated together in the code (e.g. if another search criteria is added, another table is added, conditionally to the from list and to the where clause.)  Unfortunately, the php code is quite ugly, so it's going to take me a while to get to the point where I can fully rewrite those parts of it.

Comment: Similarly the group by in the original is there to prevent duplication (replacing a select distinct that was there before) when certain code blocks come into play.  Brands is joining via a text code (e.g. 'RW' or 'CH', instead of an id, though the table itself does have valid ids on it).  I take it that tends to cause problems?  If the current "ItemsIndex" is a good candidate, then maybe it's the non-explicit joins that are the problem, I'll run a few selects with your suggested modifications and see what happens.

Comment: The select with explicit joins seems to give much the same time result  (13 seconds), but removing the group by (when I can, of course) speeds up the query to under 1 second, so I'll look into dealing with that first!